# Configure state.dir to keep state store data in different directory

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to configure my topology to change the default directory where state stores are kept.

I read from the docs the property `state.dir` is what I need to change.

The default is `/tmp/kafka-streams` and I want to change that to `/opt/kafka-streams` because in our production system, our `/tmp` directory gets peridiocally cleaned.

My application has only one topology and I have set the property `state.dir` to have the value `/opt/kafka-streams`.

In the logs I see the following being printed first which confirms that `/opt/kafka-streams` is being used:

```
   | loglevel="INFO"  |  thread="main"  |  logger="org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig  "  StreamsConfig values: 
    application.id = my-application
    application.server = 
    bootstrap.servers = [192.168.92.118:9092]
    buffered.records.per.partition = 1000
    cache.max.bytes.buffering = 10485760
    client.id = my-application-client
    commit.interval.ms = 30000
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
      ...
      ...
      ...
    state.dir = /opt/kafka-streams
```

But then ... soon after the log above, there is another log line being printed below that shows `/tmp/kafka-streams` is still being used somewhere:

```
   | loglevel="INFO"  |  thread="main"  |  logger="org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig  "  StreamsConfig values: 
    application.id = my-application
    application.server = 
    bootstrap.servers = [192.168.92.118:9092]
    buffered.records.per.partition = 1000
    cache.max.bytes.buffering = 10485760
    client.id = my-application-client-StreamThread-1-consumer
      ...
      ...
      ...
    state.dir = /tmp/kafka-streams
```

My application has only 1 topology. It is using the processor api. One processor is adding things in a state store. Then there is a punctuator that periodically reads from the state store and outputs messages on the output topic.

When building my topology I used `application.id=my-application` and `client.id=my-application-client`. But in the 2nd log line above, I see `client.id=my-application-client-StreamThread-1-consumer` and that is where `state.dir=/tmp/kafka-streams`.

Is there another place where I need to configure the `state.dir` when building my topology ?

Comment: Could you add whole starting logs and configuration?

Comment: What version are you using? Kafka Streams used to log "invalid" config what is fixed since `2.1`: https://github.com/apache/kafka/commit/487b95454233e981a65c184c7f3b86adf34058ef#diff-d3963e433c59b08688bb4481faa20e97